# comparing two paramter are same together in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I Can't code this term in GAMS

```
if there exist 
k'<k s.t. for all s ,  b(s,k')=b(s,k)  then   b(s,k)=(b(s,k-1)+b(s,k-2))/2;
else  do not Change  b(s,k)
```

```
         loop(k1$(k1.val<k.val ),
                 loop(s,
                         if( (B(s,k1)<>B(s,k1)),
                              Break;
                         else   b(s,k1)= (B(s,k1)+B(s,k1-1))/2  ;
                            );
                    );
             );
```

I don't know where I have to put Break. is it nessery to use loop over s? is teher a better way to code that?

example: in below case for s=1 and s=4 , there exist  b(s,k=1)=b(s,k=4)  then we have to update b(s,'4')=(b(s,'3')+b(s,'4') )/2

```
iter=k=4, k'={1,2,3}, s={1,2,3};

b(1,1)=3, b(2,1)=7, b(3,1)=9,

b(1,2)=2, b(2,2)=4, b(3,2)=11,

b(1,3)=5, b(2,3)=12, b(3,3)=8,

b(1,4)=3, b(2,4)=7, b(3,4)=9,
```

I used sameAs command too , but , when I used sameAs(b(s,k'),b(s,k)) (in the loop over k1) I got Error 121!

Comment: Could you post some example data and perhaps what you want the outcome to look like?

Comment: Hi @ Berenger I added an  example . Thanks

Comment: Cheers. Have put up a possible solution that might work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might work for you. Note that it relies on pairs of matches. But given that the update rule is independent of the equality condition,  that shouldn't matter here.

---

Alias `k`. (I also display `b` for clarity.)

```
alias(k,kk);

table b(s,k)

      1     2   3   4
1     3     2   5   3
2     7     4   12  7
3     9     11  8   9

;
```

Define a set `Z` over `s, k, kk`. This can pick out matches across `k`. If `k` is a subset then you need to define `Z` across the uppermost parent and an alias of it.

```
set Z(s,k,kk);
Z(s,k,kk) = no;
```

Include tuple in set `Z` when there are equal values across `k` given `s` and `kk > k`.

```
Z(s,k,kk) = yes$((b(s,k) eq b(s,kk)) and (kk.val gt k.val));

option Z:1:1:2;
display Z;
```

This defines where the matches exist. E.g. For `s=1` (rows), there is a match on `k=1` with `k=4` (columns).

```
----     26 SET Z  

          1.4

1         YES
2         YES
3         YES
```

Then we update `b` where Z is defined.

```
loop(k,
    b(s,kk)$Z(s,k,kk) = (b(s,kk) + b(s,kk-1))/2;);

display b;
```

This gives me:

```
----     31 PARAMETER b  

            1           2           3           4

1       3.000       2.000       5.000       4.000
2       7.000       4.000      12.000       9.500
3       9.000      11.000       8.000       8.500
```

Comment: Hi @Berenger , thanks!  In my code k is a dynamic subset, when I used this code I  got error. I had Set big/1*1000/ , k(big); alias(k,kk).

Comment: Which errors did you get? You should be able to adjust it so that the sets are defined with reference to big, or just define kk in the same way in which you define k.

Comment: I used `k(big)$(big.val<=iter)=yes;  ` and  `alias(k,kk)`  , 'set Z(s,k,kk);`
`Z(s,k,kk) = no; ` `  Z(s,k,kk) = yes$((b(s,k) eq b(s,kk)) and (kk.val gt k.val));`   ****   $188
 `k(big)$(big.val<=iter)=yes;;  `  Assigning to this set is NOT allowed. The set may have been
        used in a domain definition or is a predefined/readonly set.
'

Comment: I think you’ll need to define Z across the encompassing set, I.e. big, not k or kk. But it should work the same in the end. I would verify but I’m not near a computer for a while.

Comment: Something else to consider would be whether you need the set big. If your dynamic setting is just ‘less than iter’, then you could just define k from 1 to iter and run the script itself N times, where N is the size of big.

Comment: I have to define subset k such way because untill limitation of  algorthim I don't know what's the exact value of ITER

Comment: OK. Anyway, try set Z(s,big,big_) when you define Z, where big_ is an alias of big, leave the rest the same and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! ;-)

Comment: Yes! Thanks again